# Generating sequential unique code, often times occurs duplicate entry error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique-constraint

I am currently using PHP & Laravel.

What I want to do is generating a unique and sequential string as code.
In this example, the code is for Purchase Orders.

What I want is something like this:

```
PO/000001
PO/000002
PO/000003
PO/000004
PO/000005
PO/000006
```

Database table schema:

```
create table `purchase_orders` (
`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`code` varchar(191) not null, 
...
...
)

alter table `purchase_orders` add unique `purchase_orders_code_unique`(`code`)
```

This seems simple, I just need to grab the `auto_increment` ID, so the `code` corresponds with `id`, more or less like this:

```
id | code
 1 | PO/000001
 2 | PO/000002
 3 | PO/000003
 4 | PO/000004
 5 | PO/000005
 6 | PO/000006
```

The code I use: (uses Laravel's ORM syntax)

```
$count = PurchaseOrders::max('id'); // Equivalent to select MAX (`id`) from purchase_orders
$code = 'PO/' . sprintf('%08d', $count + 1);
```

In theory it works great, but in reality, often the 'collision' happens, where the `id` does not equal to the `code` it generated, sometimes the `code` is bigger/ahead than the `id`. For example, it often happens like this:

```
 id | code
... | ...
199 | PO/000199
200 | PO/000200
201 | PO/000202
```

The next transaction will have the `id` of `202`, and generated `code` is supposed to be `PO/000202`. It will trigger an **Integrity constraint violation** error, because `PO/000202` is already used on `id: 201`.

I use DB transactions & commits heavily, and sometimes creating a purchase order takes a few moment, and also there are multiple users is creating purchase orders. I don't know how exactly it happened, but the collision occurs quite often, around 100 transactions or so.

---

Here's an occurrence from a live project:
[image: id is 204, code is 205]

As you can see, that the `code` is bigger than `id`. The next code to be inserted will be `...000205`, and my client reported an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry   
'PRCV/JKT/G/2019/00000205' for key 'dlvr_payments_code_unique'
```

You can also see that the `id` and `code` is **not equal at all**

---

I also tried other code generation method before, instead of `MAX('id')` I use `COUNT(*)`, but it seems worse than `MAX('id')`.

So, the question is, what did I do wrong? How can I make it ensure a unique code every time so this won't happen again in the future?

I've been thinking of using Redis or some key-value database to store the counting, is that necessary?

Comment: Instead of making PO `code` dependent on auto-increment `id`, I would simply just fetch the last PO `code` and increment it accordingly. So basically, just before inserting a new PO record, get an explicit lock on the table using `LOCK TABLE purchase_orders;` Now fetch the Last PO `code` using `SELECT code FROM purchase_orders ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;` Process it in PHP, increment it and now fire `INSERT` query. Dont forget to release the explicit lock at end: `UNLOCK TABLES;`

Comment: do not depend on `max(id)` to generate `code`. instead you should think of using `last generated code` to create new code.

Comment: maintaining of another table on generated used codes is good. it should only contain one record on `code` with last used code. once generating new code based on this, update this record.

Comment: u can store id to other table. from here u can get last inserted id. or after insertion u can update it. if u deleted last item max(id) does never work.

Comment: @topher possible to use the current timestamp... as it would be unique all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it!

Don't depend on **PK** in order to achieve sequential number. It leaves you in various end streets.

I would recommend to store your last inserted **Purchase Order** ID in a separate table and keep updating it accordingly.

Along with maintaining a table, having it stored in cache (ie redis) can improve your application's performance.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @topher you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful  ;)